# Almost selfadjointness in tempered distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $\mathbb{F}=\{f^{(s)}\}_{s\in{\mathbb{R}^d}}$ a collection of tempered distributions in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $F=\{h\in S(\mathbb{R}^d)\,:\,\mbox{the map }s\mapsto f^{(s)}(h)\mbox{ is in }S(\mathbb{R}^d)\}$.

Is there some class of general conditions about $\mathbb{F}$ in order to obtain $\boldsymbol{\langle f^{(\cdot)}(u),v\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}=\langle u,f^{(\cdot)}(v)\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}}$ **for all** $\boldsymbol{u,v\in F}$?

That is: Are there some set of conditions over $\mathbb{F}$, say $P(\mathbb{F})$, such that **bold text** is true if and only if $P(\mathbb{F})$ is true.

**Note:**
The inner product is explicitelly $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f^{(s)}(u)v(s)\,\mathrm{d}s=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u(s)f^{(s)}(v)\,\mathrm{d}s.$$

Comment: Thus, if we define $T_f : F \to S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by $(T_f h)(s) = f^{(s)}(h)$ then you want conditions for $\langle T_f u, v \rangle = \langle u, T_f v \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, so the original question can be interpreted in an Operator Theory approach (for example, if $T$ is symmetric, selfadjoint, etc.)